# VIM-Bootstrap on Debian 9

Tags: vim, stretch

Has anyone a solution for working VIM-Bootstrap on Debian 9?
URL: https://vim-bootstrap.com/

1st error:

> E185: Cannot find color scheme 'molokai'
>  Press ENTER or type
>   command to continue

Solution:
Download molokai.vim and copy to /usr/share/vim/vim80/colors/molokai.vim

URL: https://github.com/tomasr/molokai/blob/master/colors/molokai.vim

2nd Error

> line 1
>  E682 invalid search pattern or separator
>  Press ENTER or
>   type command to continue

I found no solution.
Line 1 Code is:

```
vim-bootstrap b0a75e4
```

VIM-Bootstrap worked until 90%, but still has on every start this error message.

Comment: The first line should be `" vim-bootstrap b0a75e4`. Also, that config is filled to the brim with ugly hacks and anti-patterns. Don't use it.

Comment: That colorscheme should have been downloaded and installed automatically by the `Plug 'tomasr/molokai'` line. If that doesn't work, fix your environment, or better start from scratch without such predefined configuration. Vim "distributions" like _spf-13_ and _Janus_ lure you with a quick install and out-of-the-box settings, but you pay the price with increased complexity (you need to understand both Vim's runtime loading scheme and the arbitrary conventions of the distribution) and inflexibility (the distribution may make some things easier, but other things very difficult).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to :PlugInstall?

this supposed to bring all vimrc pluggins. one of them is your color scheme.
checkout my 
[.vimrc](https://github.com/reubinoff/DotFiles/blob/master/.vimrc)